# Prove the following inequality for all real numbers a,b,c,d

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

In this question I think we take the cyclic summation.... I am not familiar with it and could not understand it.Could you please help me and explain it in a easy way. Also how to you go about solving this problem?

Thanks in advance

I am familiar with AM-GM-HM-RMS inequality and Cauchy Schwarz inequality.
$$\frac{a}{b+2c+3d}+\frac{b}{c+2d+3a}+\frac{c}{d+2a+3b}+\frac{d}{a+2b+3c}\geq\frac{2}{3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$x = b+2c+3d, \quad y = c+2d+3a,  \quad z = d+2a+3b,  \quad t = a+2b+3c,$$
then
$$a = \frac{z+t-5x+7y}{24},  \quad b = \frac{t+x-5y+7z}{24},$$
$$c = \frac{x+y-5z+7t}{24},  \quad d = \frac{y+z-5t+7x}{24}.$$
The inequality become
$$\left(\frac x z+\frac z x\right)+\left(\frac t y+\frac y t\right)+\left(\frac x y+\frac y z+\frac  zt+\frac tx\right) + 7\left(\frac y x+\frac zy+\frac tz+\frac xt\right)\geqslant 36.$$
Which is true by the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: The question has been asked and answered before (and a possible duplicate target has already been pointed out). It is preferable to add additional answers to the older question  (and vote to close as a duplicate) so that all solutions to a problem are in one place.

Comment: @MartinR I am new to stack exchange and could not comment on it because of my reputation that's why I asked it here